# Dropdown list of buttons

Tags: android

First I want to mention that I am a beginner in android.

Basically I am trying to implement the Microsoft's calculator in android.For now I am implementing only the UI.
Is it possible to make a dropdown list of buttons?

[image]

Like in this picture when you select `Bitwise` a list of buttons appears.Also is it possible `Bitwise` also to be a button and if not to act like one?

Comment: you can use spinner with custom item in adapter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
you must use a custom spinner.
By custom spinner, you can add any layout you like to your spinner; so you can create a layout that has a button.

You can search for `Android custom spinner` and learn about that.
I will give you an educational link about that.

[How to add Custom Spinner in android?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-custom-spinner-in-android/)